# React protected route using axios & JWT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, jwt, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a protected route with Reatjs, nodejs and JWT. The problem is that my component renders before my API checked the client token. This is the code I am trying :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthAPI from './../utils/AuthAPI';


const ProtectedRoute = ({children, ...rest}) => {

    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        await AuthAPI.isAuth((res)=>{ //API call
            setIsAuth(res); 
        });
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData();
    },[]);

    return (
        <Route {...rest} 
            render={(props)=>{
                return(
                    isAuth ? children : <Redirect to='/' />
                );
            }} 
        />
    );

};
```

And this is the API call :

```
static isAuth(callback){ //static method from the class 'AuthAPI' imported above
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Auth/checking';
    const options = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                },
                data: {}
            }
    return axios(options)
    .then((response)=>{
        callback(true);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        callback(false);
    });
}
```

When I load the page, it directly redirects since the state isAuth is set to false by default.
I already used this model of code to display a list of things gotten from an API and it worked fine. I assume it is not the best way to do that but most of the examples I have found are not using an actual API but just fake auth without using promises.

**EDIT 1.2 :**

I've tried this code, from Udendu Abasili :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthAPI from './../utils/AuthAPI';


const ProtectedRoute = ({children, ...rest}) => {

    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)

    useEffect(()=>{
        let mounted = true;

        AuthAPI.isAuth().then(()=>{
            if (mounted) {
                console.log("Worked"); //display Worked
                setIsLoaded(true); // This line 1
                setIsAuth(true); // This line 2
            }
        }).catch(()=>{
            if (mounted) {
                console.log("Failed"); 
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setIsAuth(false);
            }
        });

        return () => {
            mounted = false;
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        !isLoaded ?
            <h5>Loading</h5> : (
            <Route {...rest} 
                render={(props)=>{
                    console.log("--->",isAuth,",",isLoaded); // displays false, true
                    return(
                        isAuth ? children : <Redirect to='/' />
                    );
                }}
            /> 
        )
    );

};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I have found a weird bug. If I swap the lines commented as 'line 1' and 'line 2', it works otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: so when you load the page what shows up first?

Comment: When I load the page, there is a redirection in any case. My state is set to false by default.

Comment: You just need three states, unknown, true, false. True, false is set when the call completes, unknown is default. Unknown doesn't redirect.

Comment: Ok ! I am trying this, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The way react js lifecycle works, the return component gets called before `useEffect`(which the hook equivalent of componentDidMount on the first mount). So you need to create a form of loader component ( replace the `<Text>Loading</Text>` with an actual CSS loader ) that waits for your isAuth function to finish.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({children, ...rest}) => {

    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      //you need to add try catch here 
        await AuthAPI.isAuth((res)=>{ //API call
            setIsAuth(res); 
            setLoaded(true)
        });
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData();
    },[]);

    return (
        loaded ?
            <Text>Loading</Text> : (
        <Route {...rest} 
            render={(props)=>{
                return(
                    isAuth ? children : <Redirect to='/' />
                );
            }} 
        )
        />
    );

};
```

As you rightfully said, this is not the best way to do it. I won't recommend calling a function to check authentication in the protected route component. Typically, I just pass an isAuthenticated paramter to ProctectedRoute  component which gets updated with help of Redux. You should look it up

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and adapted your code since I got unmounted component warning but it still doesn't work. I've edited my first post to describe what I did and what I got.

Comment: I have edited my first message : actually, it works fine only if I set setIsAuth before setIsLoaded. Otherwise, isLoaded gets true before isAuth and then redirected.